# How to get JSON array from web api with retrofit and active android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I have an web api which gives me array of partners and it looks like this:

```
[ 
  "partner1",
  "partner2",
  "partner3",
  "....",
  "parner222"
]
```

I have Table partners (ActiveAndroid) in which I would like to save all partners from api.

```
@Table(name = "Partners")
public class Partners extends Model {

    @Column(name = "Name")
    String name;

    public Partners() {}

    public Partners(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is my Pojo model class:

```
public class Partners {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

This is my interface

```
public interface APIService {

        @GET("Partners")
        Call<Partners> getPartners();
}
```

And this is my APIHelper with api url

```
public class APIHelper {

    public static APIService apiService;

    public static APIService getApiService() {
        if (apiService == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://part-oflink.domain.com/partners.json/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        }
        return apiService;
    }
}
```

And this is Fragment where I have an Button on which I would like to implement onClick method to get data from API and save it into Partners table.

```
public class DownloadMain extends Fragment implements Callback<Partners> {

    private Button dloadPartners;
    private Call<Partners> callPartners;
    public static APIService apiService;

    public DownloadMain() {}

    public DownloadMain newInstance() { return new DownloadMain(); }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.download_main, container, false);

        dloadPartners = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.downloadPartners);
        dloadPartners.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

        callPartners = APIHelper.getApiService().getPartners();
        callPartners.enqueue(this);

        return view;
    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnListener = (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //here I need to implement that on click downloads me data
            // and save it into my Partners table
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Partners> call, Response<Partners> response) {

        //here I'm trying to put api response into array list
        if (response.body() != null) {
            ArrayList<String> partnersList = new ArrayList<>();
            partnersList = response.body();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Partners> call, Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

And now I have stuck. I would like to implement onClick Button method to get data from API. In onResponse() method I'm trying to put data into ArrayList to check if data is recieved. And also I would like to save this data into my table partners.

I would be grateful if someone could help me or guide me to fix this. This is first time I'm doing with retrofit and api.

Can somebody help me or guide me to successfully get data from API and save it into table Partners?

Comment: please log partnersList variable output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to parse the JSON string(array of partners) is not the appropriate. Your JSON should like this:

```
{
"partners": 
  ["partner1", "partner2", "partner3", ...]
}
```

And the POJO model class should be:

```
class Partners{
    private List<String> partners;

    public Partners(){}

    public void setList(List<String> partners) {
        this.partners = partners;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
       return this.partners;
    }

    //setter and getter methods
}
```

Comment: so my JSON is not good? I have check api url with postman and get response like in question above.
Another question.. I have my table Partners, can I create POJO in there or create new model class for POJO?

Comment: Does partnersList variable contain your partners data?

Comment: You can use pojo model by this website http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, It will convert json response message to model, Then you can use GreenDao to insert to table.

Comment: can you please log what partnersList contains?

Comment: partnerList throws me an error `Error:(69, 41) error: incompatible types
required: ArrayList<String>
found:    Partners`

Answer (score 0):

If the response is not empty then for printing the values:

```
for(Partner partner: response){

Log.d("Partner Name",partner.name);

}
```

And if you are using any ORM for the database, then call its DAO and pass the values to save in the DB.

Comment: Response in for loop throws me `foreach not applicable to type retrofit2`